# wpa_supplicant on lucid

Tags: wifi, ubuntu-10.04

I'm trying to get my wifi working through the command line, but I'm not having success. I generated the wpa_supplicant.conf with wpa_passphrase and I'm running `wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`. I only receive as a clue "Disconnect event - remove keys" and I get associated. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spent the last few days looking at ways of doing this for auto logging in netbooks I have set up. I am running Debian, but the process should work for you as well.

Rather than use */etc/wpa_supplicant.conf*, try setting your wireless connection in */etc/network/interfaces*. The wireless part of my file looks like this:

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid your_ssid_here
wpa-ap-scan 1
wpa-prooto RSN
wpa-pairwise TKIP
wpa-group TKIP
wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
wpa-psk your_generated_key_here
auto wlan0
```

This makes the assumption your wireless access point broadcasts its name and uses WPA2 and TKIP.

You can check that your wireless device is working ok, and is finding access points, with the commands *iwconfig* and *iwlist*.

Also, another problem I ran into was that my network interfaces were not coming up correctly and not getting DHCP addresses on boot, so I added a call to *dhclient* in my login script to renew the address. This seemed more graceful than when I used to restart all network interfaces entirely.